# Cleaning the screens of phones

Tags: cleaning, phone

I don't have a liquid solution specially made to clean the screens of phones. So what's the substitute for that?
I can't use only a cloth since my screen has got stains.
So can I use sanitizer/ lens solution?
Or is there a better substitute?
I need a solution for a stain on my phone's screen.
Since for fingerprint marks I simply use a spectacles' cloth

Comment: Rubbing alcohol might be suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The safest method is to use a lint free cloth (preferably), moistened with soapy water.

Comment: Is that safe? Have you ever used it?

Comment: Yes, I have.  It's probably the most conservative thing you could do.

Answer (score 2):

I always use Lens Cleaning Wipes, originally meant to clean my glasses, but they can also clean phones:

[image: Lens wipes]

Using one once a week or so is enough in my case. I use the same wipe for glasses and phone, and it works as each wipe is pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on the kind of dirt which is deposited on the screen.

For the most of the cases (no exceptions so far) I used 2 methods:

- use some clean dry cotton cloth - dry cleaning; removes mostly dust and natural finger grease;
- use some wet clean cotton cloth to wash stubborn spots, then apply the fist method for finishing.

I use smartphones for about 10 years, and the above always worked.

NOTE: I am careful and I do not "apply" on the screen unneeded garbage: greases, chocolates, paints...

Answer (score 1):

I was supremely paranoid about how to clean my laptop screen and my smartphone at first so I spent an inordinate amount of time researching on the web and bought 'the #1 rated formula' spray for LCD, DLP, Plasma, cell phone screens+ from Fry's, I think.  It is called Klear Screen; just now found more info.  This is what I bought, but the bottle labeling has changed so it is not as informative (at least not at this site and same at Amazon; $9.95 at both sites now)
https://klearscreen.com/collections/klear-screen/products/ks-8

[https://www.amazon.com/Klear-Screen-Refill-Bottle-KS-8/dp/B00013ZCMW/ref=pd_lpo_147_t_0/144-0642832-3170718?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00013ZCMW&pd_rd_r=03085b18-a137-4305-b4bf-3197b934b283&pd_rd_w=JL665&pd_rd_wg=qBEA8&pf_rd_p=16b28406-aa34-451d-8a2e-b3930ada000c&pf_rd_r=NAZM9WNXMVGDHFXR865A&psc=1&refRID=NAZM9WNXMVGDHFXR865A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00013ZCMW)

but there is an abundance of info at their FAQs page
https://klearscreen.com/pages/frequently-asked-questions
Pix of my bottle:
[image: front]
[image: back]
[image: side-UPC-KS8]

Now for both, I often just breathe on them (with the screens off) and wipe with a soft washcloth.  For the smartphone, when I'm out and about, same thing only I wipe it on my slacks or blouse...depending on a number of quick considerations (which is cleaner and which don't I mind wiping my phone on at the time.  If at first I don't succeed, I repeat until clean. Not paranoid anymore, works just fine and I didn't die and my laptop and cell screens are unscathed as well.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little different.  I only buy waterproof phones.  When I want to clean them, I follow this procedure (obviously don't try this if your phone isn't waterproof):

1. I put a tiny dot of gentle dishwashing detergent on the back of my hand.
2. I then tap the screen of the phone to the back of my hand to transfer an *ever-so-small* amount of the detergent to the screen's surface.
3. I run a little bit of water over the device and use my fingers to wipe all surfaces of the phone.
4. I rinse the phone for a couple seconds.
5. *Tadaaa!* The phone is now wonderfully clean.
6. I then use the rest of the dot of dishwashing detergent on the back of my hand to wash my hands.
7. *Tadaaa!* Clean hands too!

Although I cannot make any guarantees, I've personally done this for years without any issues.

This procedure the ***big added bonus*** of likely cleaning off bacteria and possibly even SARS-Co-V2 (the virus that causes COVID-19) from your phone.  If you want a better chance of removing any SARS-Co-V2 virion, perform steps 3 and 4 for at least 3 seconds each.  My understanding is that soap helps destroy the shell around SARS-Co-V2 virion after about 30 seconds of rubbing, rendering the remaining RNA harmless.